# How to regain access to folder in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I used this bat script file to hide a folder called "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"

```
cls 
@ECHO OFF 
title Hello
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST MyFolder goto MDMyFolder 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure to lock this folder? (Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren MyFolder "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to Unlock Your Secure Folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== fucku goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" MyFolder 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDMyFolder
md MyFolder
echo MyFolder created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```

It was working perfectly until today.  Now when i try to unlock this folder, it wont work. I'm on windows 8.1.

In the command prompt if I type `dir /a:h` it shows me that the directory is there.

But when I use the command `attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"` It says:

> Access denied to folder "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"

Comment: Have you tried running Command Prompt as Administrator then running your script?

Comment: Hey thanks for your fast reply. I just tried as Administrator and i got the folder back, but the folder is empty now. All the files and sub folders are gone!

Comment: Your script is really only doing two things, renaming the folder from/to "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" and applying/removing the system and hidden attributes. You can try [showing hidden files](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27479) to see if they are hidden still...

Comment: Try rebooting first.

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks very much James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use that "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" in your path. Append it to where you have "MyFolder" at.